# wake up or delete work of workqueue linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

i have a work of a workqueue that in his function has a msleep(). Is there some function to wake up the work or to delete it without waiting that it finishes to sleep? Or maybe is there same delay functions interruptible inside a work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If work is currently executed, it cannot be just stopped without being completed.
Normally, `msleep()` can be interrupted with `wake_up_process(task)`, but from the outside you don't know the process(task) where workqueue is executed.

If you want pause in your work to be interruptible outside, you should use wake_up-aware function. E.g., `wait_for_completion_timeout`:

```
DECLARE_COMPLETION(comp);

void work_func(struct work* work)
{
    ...
    // sleep for *m* miliseconds
    if(wait_for_completion_timeout(&comp, msecs_to_jiffies(m)))
    {
        // sleep has been interrupted
    }
    ...
}

some_func()
{
    ...
    // No futher needs to work
    complete(&comp);
}
```

Note, that `*_timeout` functions use *jiffies* for count intervals.